# Notification on group update Facebook

Tags: javascript, web

I can't seem to find an answer to my question but apologies if there is one.

I'd like to set something up where a notification is sent to a user when a facebook page updates their events list.

How would I go about this using JavaScript?

Still relatively new to all of this so any pointers on where to begin are appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

There is no short answer to your question but here is a starting point:

1. If you have admin/dev rights for the page you want to send notifications for see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks Also, if you look closely to the Facebook development documentation you will find that you can email all your users as a newsletter.
2. If you are not the owner or have no rights to the page then you pretty much need to write a web-scraper check this article: https://medium.com/data-scraper-tips-tricks/scraping-data-with-javascript-in-3-minutes-8a7cf8275b31 and once you have that you will need to build a mechanism for your mailing list to be emailed. Check MailChip's API page here: https://developer.mailchimp.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this!